# dvipng: limit cropping in a single direction

Tags: spacing, conversion, png

I know that `-tight` switch arranges the image size to include all the ink on the page. For this instance, however, I want to give a width of my choice and crop only in the vertical direction.

Furthermore I only want to crop the space *below* the image.

Is this possible without modifying the dvipng source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to follow would be to disable cropping altogether with dvipng, and using ImageMagick to enable [flexible trimming](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_oneside).